# When should [early-universe] end?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Do we want it to be equal to the definition at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#The_early_universe), i.e. ending with [cmb](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cmb)?

Currently we have questions like these:

1. [Will James Webb see Population III stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/will-james-webb-see-population-iii-stars)
2. [Characteristics of the first planets in the Universe?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33581/characteristics-of-the-first-planets-in-the-universe)

Which cover a period much later than CMB.

The [early-universe](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/early-universe) wiki excerpt currently says

> Questions regarding the universe shortly after it's formation

Comment: We should definitely fix that rogue apostrophe as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [UC Berkeley page](http://cosmology.berkeley.edu/Education/CosmologyEssays/The_Standard_Cosmology.html) seems to peg the CMB as the end of the early universe period. We should give a little bit for some of our astrophysics professionals around here to weigh in, but otherwise I think that's what we should go with.

Answer (score 4):

Several sites ([The First Stars and Galaxies](https://www.physics.uu.se/research/astronomy-and-space-physics/research/galaxies/first-stars-galaxies/), for example) place the formation of the first stars as happening in the early universe period. This happened well after the CMB. [NASA](https://webbtelescope.org/webb-science/early-universe) pegs the early universe as ending even later with the formation of the first galaxies. This is in line with the two questions raised in this meta question.

Comment: Thanks for adding that